# horizontally aligning DIVs with fixed and dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up the following `div` blocks so that the left `div` nd the right `div` are of fixed width and the centre `div` dynamically expands as needed. The right `div` floats to right and the left to left, so that the entire screen is used. The setup I have right now works fine as long as the text in the centre `div` spans through the entire center `div` when it starts pushing the right `div` under the center `div`.

```
+------------------------+
| THIS   IS THE    TITLE |
|                        |
+------------------------+
| LEFT | CENTER  | RIGHT |
| DIV  | DIV     | DIV   |
|      |         |       |
|      |         |       |
|      |         |       |
|      |         |       |
+------+---------+-------+
| THIS   IS THE  BOTTOM  |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

My CSS is:

```
#leftbar{float:left;width:162px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
#center{float:left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;padding-left:10px;}
#rightbar{float:right;width:162px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
#clearbothbar{clear:both;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='top'></div>
<div id='leftbar'></div>
<div id='center'></div>
<div id='rightbar'></div>
<div id='clearbothbar'></div>
<div id='bottom'></div>
```

I know I could put a fixed width for the center `div` and be done with it but I would like the center area to dynamically shrink on smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it really simple, use `float:right` and `float:left flor side divs` and separate the middle one using margin-right. **Please put attention that the left and right divs order is important in this solution.**
Your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtorrescr/gAwv2/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="top">TOP</div>
<div id='leftbar'></div>
<div id='rightbar'></div>
<div id='center'></div>
<div id='clearbothbar'></div>
<div id="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
```

css:

```
#top, #bottom
{
    background-color:green;
}
#container
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#rightbar
{
    float:right;
    width:162px;
    background-color:pink;
    height:300px;
}
#leftbar
{
    float:left;  
    width:162px;
    background-color:orange;
    height:300px;
}
#center
{
    margin-right:162px; 
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;

}

#clearbothbar
{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will need a bit more fiddling around, but just generally you can change the left and right div to position:absolute and then put the center div in the middle with margin-left and margin-right as the width of the left and right div.

```
<style>
    html, body {margin:0;padding:0;}
    div {border: solid black 1px; min-height: 50px;}
    #leftbar{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:162px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    #center{
    margin: 0 163px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    }
    #rightbar{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:162px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -52px;
    }
    #clearbothbar{clear:both;height:0;min-height:0;border:none;}
</style>

<div id='top'>top</div>
<div id='leftbar'>left</div>
<div id='center'>center</div>
<div id='rightbar'>right</div>
<div id='clearbothbar'></div>
<div id='bottom'>bottom</div>
```